# Get the records count per partition in spark using dataframe without ignoring empty partition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, partition

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id

df.groupBy(spark_partition_id).count

Above example is not showing empty partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can achieve this with `mapPartitions`:

```scala
# We first coalesce to 5 partitions only for display purposes:
df.coalesce(5).mapPartitions(it => Iterator(it.size)).show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    0|
|    0|
|    0|
|    0|
|    1|
+-----+
```